# EnumDropDownListFor using Reflection throwing "Return type 'System.Object' is not supported."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'm trying to build out a settings page using reflection. Some options are enums, but the standard `@Html.EditorFor()` gives a text box rather than a dropdown on these properties. I have an approach sort-of working using `@Html.DropDownList()`, but I want the "for" helper to get the benefits of having the value pre-selected.

### Classes

```
public class CycleSettings
{
    //a bunch of sub-objects, like:
    public SurveyConfiguration Survey { get; set; }
}

public class SurveyConfiguration
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    [DisplayName("Display Survey Data")]
    public DataDisplayFullOptions Data { get; set; }
}

public enum DataDisplayFullOptions
{
    Available,
    [Display(Name = "Coming Soon")]
    ComingSoon,
    Report
}
```

### View

```
@foreach (var property in typeof(CycleSettings).GetProperties()) {
    object temp = property.GetValue(Model.Settings.CycleSettings[Model.CurrentYear][Model.CurrentCycle]);
    @Html.Label(property.Name)
    <div style="padding-left: 20px">
        @foreach (var subprop in temp.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object temp2 = subprop.GetValue(temp);
            var label = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(subprop, typeof (DisplayNameAttribute));
            @Html.Label(label != null ? ((DisplayNameAttribute)label).DisplayName : subprop.Name,new {@style="padding-right: 20px"})
            @(temp2.GetType().IsEnum ? Html.EnumDropDownListFor((m) => temp2) : Html.EditorFor((m) => temp2)) //error occurs here on EnumDropDownListFor path
            /*Html.DropDownList(subprop.Name, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(temp2.GetType()))*/ //this worked, but I am trying to use the EnumDropDownListFor to get the correct property selected on load
            <br/>
        }
    </div>
}
```

### Stack Trace

> [ArgumentException: Return type 'System.Object' is not supported.
>   Parameter name: expression]
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1
>   htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2
>   htmlAttributes) +1082
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1
>   htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, String optionLabel) +90

**EDIT:** Just tried this-- no more error, but still not selecting the right value:

```
Html.DropDownListFor((m) => temp2, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(temp2.GetType()))
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: No. That's your ASP.NET version, most likely. There's no MVC 4.5 and the version numbers of MVC and ASP.NET don't line up. MVC 4 and MVC 5 both run on ASP.NET 4 or 4.5. MVC 6 (still pre-release) will actually run on ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Sorry again :P MVC 5.2.2.0 -- I did end up figuring it out (see answer below) but thanks for looking!

Comment: You're not using a custom HtmlHelper extension for `EnumDropDownListFor` are you? MVC 5 has one built in, and you should be able to use that with minimal fuss: `Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.SomeEnumProperty)`

Comment: Yes, I was trying to utilize that built-in one in the code above, but I was getting the error I described. It doesn't seem to work with the way I'm using reflection.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is why are you using reflection in the first place. There might be a valid reason, but generally speaking, acceptable uses of reflection are few and far between in application code. It's really for meta programming like building Visual Studio extensions that process compiled code. Entity Framework, for example, uses reflection because there's really no way it could function without it, but that's one of those rare exceptions where it's acceptable out of necessity.

Comment: Unfortunately, the design decision on this page (not made by me) was to use reflection so that when options are changed in the object (added/removed) it would be automatically propagated to the view. I didn't think updating the view would be a big deal and would give us a greater degree of control, but again, this was the decision that was made and what I had to work within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple. I was close with this attempt:

```
Html.DropDownListFor((m) => temp2, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(temp2.GetType()))
```

I just needed to [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn550797(v=vs.118).aspx) the `GetSelectList`:

```
Html.DropDownListFor((m) => temp2, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(temp2.GetType(), (Enum)temp2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my enum extensions I usually use. Hope it can help.

```
public enum Gender
{
    [EnumDescription("Not selected")]
    NotSelected,
    [EnumDescription("Male")]
    Male,
    [EnumDescription("Female")]
    Female
}
```

In your view (you can omit "data-bind" Knockout binding)

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "gender",
    SelectListExt.ToSelectList(typeof(Gender)),
    new
    {
        data_bind = "value: Gender",
    })
```

Select list helper class:

```
public static class SelectListExt
{
    public static SelectList ToSelectList(Type enumType)
    {
        return ToSelectList(enumType, String.Empty);
    }

    public static SelectList ToSelectList(Type enumType, string selectedItem)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            FieldInfo fi = enumType.GetField(item.ToString());
            var attribute = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDescription), true).FirstOrDefault();
            var title = attribute == null ? item.ToString() : ((EnumDescription)attribute).Text;

            // uncomment to skip enums without attributes
            //if (attribute == null)
            //    continue;

            var listItem = new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = ((int)item).ToString(),
                Text = title,
                Selected = selectedItem == ((int)item).ToString()
            };
            items.Add(listItem);
        }

        return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", selectedItem);
    }
}
```

And the attribute itself:

```
public class EnumDescription : Attribute
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public EnumDescription(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

You can also use my extension class to convert enums to their string descriptions:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToDescription(this Enum enumeration)
    {
        Type type = enumeration.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(enumeration.ToString());

        if (null != memInfo && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDescription), false);
            if (null != attrs && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((EnumDescription)attrs[0]).Text;
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }

        return enumeration.ToString();
    }
}
```

This code is not perfect, but it works for me. Feel free to refactor and post updates!

Comment: 1) The OP is using MVC 5 which has a helper built-in for enums. 2) Why are you using a custom attribute, `EnumDescription`? You can simply use `Display(Name = "Foo")` with your enum members.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ah, ok. Custom attribute is used because there were some other logic related to this.